# React Native: can't find variable: StyleSheet

Tags: react-native, styles

I'm trying to style a Text element but I'm getting the following error:

**Can't find variable: StyleSheet**

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

const Header = () => (
    <Text style = {styles.textStyle}>This is the header</Text>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   textStyle: {
      fontSize: 20
  }
});
export default Header;
```

I can figure out what the problem is, did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

import StyleSheet before using it.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sricharan